# How do I know if someone deleted/quit the shared folder in Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

I shared (I'm the owner) a Dropbox folder with a friend before. We had an argument. So, we haven't talked to each other for a while. When I checked my Dropbox, I can still see that I'm sharing the folder with her. How do I know if she still has a copy of this folder? In another words, if she deleted her copy, is there a way that I can know about it? Or, if I add more files in the shared folder, will she see the files as well (even she deleted the folder)?

Answer (score 2):

If she is still part of the shared folder's usergroup, it does not matter if she deleted the folder from her computer or wherever, she can still at any point login to Dropbox and download any file's within the shared folder at will.

The only way to ensure she doesn’t get to the file's contained within the folder are:

1. Copy the files that you don't want her to see to an unshared Dropbox folder.
2. Unshare the folder with her (in sharing options, evict her from the list of people the folder is shared with).